# Where can we find a list of hazardous substance codes used in OSHA violation data?

Tags: labor

We're trying to figure out how to make meaningful the responses in "hazsub1" through "hazsub5" in OSHA violation data. you can see the list of variables here

https://developer.dol.gov/health-and-safety/dol-osha-enforcement/

but for the life of us we can't figure out what 4-digit alphanumeric list of hazards the results corresponds to. Please help!

Comment: It's tough to say based on their documentation. Could be the analyte codes listed here https://www.osha.gov/chemicaldata/ or EPA hazardous waste codes https://gecap.org/pdf/hazardouswastecodes.pdf or maybe a combination of both. Probably best to email them and ask for clarification.